# Sort blank entries to bottom of LINQ query

Tags: vb.net, linq, linq-to-sql, sorting, sql-order-by

I am trying to sort a LINQ to SQL query based on two fields.  The first field is occasionally null which automatically sorts to the top of an ascending query.  Is there any way to make the null entries sort to the bottom?

Here is an example:

```
From x in SampleDataContext.Event _
Order By x.Date, x.Sequence_Number _
Select x.Date, x.Sequence_Number
```

Would return:

- NULL, 1
- NULL, 4
- 12/2/09, 5
- 12/3/09, 2
- 12/3/09, 3

Desired order:

- 12/2/09, 5
- 12/3/09, 2
- 12/3/09, 3
- NULL, 1
- NULL, 4

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If they're strings:

```
Order By (string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Date) ? "zzzzzz" : x.Date)
```

If they're nullable datetimes:

```
Order By (x.Date ?? DateTime.MaxValue)
```

Comment: nice, didnt know you could do that